# Rules of predicate calculus logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

There is signature $\sigma = \left \langle P^{2} \right \rangle$ , **P** - predicate, **t** - term signature $\sigma$.

I need to prove that the rule $\frac{\Gamma ,\Phi (t))\vdash \Psi }{\Gamma , \forall x \Phi (x))\vdash \Psi }$ is not a valid rule. It means its addition to the predicate calculus can extend the set of provable sequents. Also I understend This rule is not deducible, so we can find a algebraic system of our signature where it doesn't work.

I have some problems, because it doesn't looks like not valid. I qlearly know that there is such rule $ \frac{\Gamma ,\Phi (x)_{t}^{x})\vdash \Psi }{\Gamma , \forall x \Phi (x))\vdash \Psi } $. Also our signature has only one predicate symbol, so **t** can be only variable.  So if $\Phi (x)$ true $\forall x$ then it true for a special one.

Comment: If you look closely at the rule you quoted, you'll probably find some restriction intended to prevent variables from becoming accidentally quantified when you substitute $t$ for $x$. (The relevant terminology might be "substitutable" or "free for" or freely substitutable", depending on the author's taste.) Try to concoct a situation where that restriction is violated; see whether you can arrange it so that the resulting rule isn't sound.